# Function, return value using pwd in KSH

Tags: ksh, function

I tried to write a small `ksh` script:

```
fDestExists (){
    cd /tmp
    read vANSWER?" >> Do you want to create a repository in pwd ? Type YES or NO"
        echo "    |----> $(fGetDatum) You typed: " $vANSWER         
        if [ "$vANSWER" = "YES" ]; then
                read vANSWER2?" >> Type your repository's name."
                mkdir -p $vANSWER2
                cd $vANSWER2
                echo "    |----> Logs will be coped in pwd."        
        elif [ "$vANSWER" = "NO" ]; then
            echo "    |----> Logs will be coped in pwd."        
        else 
            echo "    |----> You typed a wrong answer; exiting."        
            exit 1
        fi  
    pwd #return
}
```

Several questions here.

1. How can I use pwd's value in my echo?
2. To return value, I read it was feasible using echo [yourValue] at last line. Then where you call the function, I guess I can use : $?. So how can I do the same behaviour with pwd?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1: you can directly use the PWD variable, eg:

```
echo "    |----> Logs will be coped in $PWD."
```

2: `$?` is used to retrieve the last command return value which is numerical. There is no way to pass a string here, the return value should be 0 meaning success or something different meaning some failure. Use `return 0` or `return -1` if you want to get that information. As you are modifying the script current directory, it will be available as `$PWD` in the caller side anyway.

Comment: Can I ask you one more question ?
Is there any conventions about how writting script in KSH ? Like doing systematically "unset" to variables I use ? Or always using typeset to define new variables.

Comment: @user1058398 if the question is about details in this answer, you should just write them in a comment. Otherwise (or if you can word that request for details as a complete question) just put up a new question, possible refering to this one as background info.